# UX members: you're invited to submit articles to Smashing Magazine!

Tags: discussion

Over the years I've become close friends with designer [Francisco Inchauste](http://www.getfinch.com/). He's written many fantastic articles on design.

Last year he became the editor in charge for the [UX section](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/) of Smashing Magazine. He's always looking for great UX article submissions or people who are interested in becoming reviewers for articles. If you're interested, please email him your draft or any questions you may have to francisco.inchauste@smashingmagazine.com

Here's Smashing Magazine's official page on how to become an author/reviewer:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/how-to-become-a-smashing-magazine-author/

P.S. authors/reviewers are compensated, so this is not free volunteer work:

> All of our authors get paid. The amount of money depends on the length
>   of the article and its quality. Before your articles go live, we make
>   sure that both sides agree upon the publishing and payment conditions.
>   You can also put a link to your website in the “About the
>   author”-section in the article.

I told Francisco that we have a great UX community here, it'd be a win-win if some of us get published on SM. They get great content and UX.SE gets some exposure in the design community. SM forbids self-promotional posts so our articles shouldn't come off as an advertisement for UX.SE. I think it's reasonable to put "I'm an active contributor/mod on UX.se" in the author bio, if the article gets published.

Comment: I think people who successfully publish something on SM should get a silver badge or something. You know how UX.SE members work - they're in it for the rep! They don't care about the money! ;)

Comment: This is a great example of the importance of participating in the social web - it's a nice, concrete example of a great company looking for good writers. SM gets to source, contact and identify good writers through good character and social participation!

Comment: What about people who publish on UX Mag? Or other publications? It is hard to tell the quality because it is not a journal and therefore not subject to peer review, but you can still judge the relative quality by comments and feedback from the audience.